# First time setting up a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, lamp

In trying to learn how to work with the LAMP stack, I've hit a wall with MySQL. I can't seem to find a good reference for the first time setup of MySQL to be used with Apache and python. So, my question is four-fold:

1) Under what circumstances should I create my first database. That is, what user do I use (Apache's http user? root?)

2)How do permissions work?

3) Do I have to do anything on the MySQL side to make MySQL talk to Apache, or MySQL to talk to Python/Django?

4) Is there a good resource online that describes setting all of this up? I've found a bunch for using a database once it's in place, but none for the initial setup?

Notes: I'm trying to run my LAMP stack on a dedicated little box for testing/learning purposes only, so I don't have access to any DBA that could help me, as much as I'd like one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Under what circumstances should I create my first database. That is, what user do I use (Apache's http user? root?)

You create a database when you want to store data in it.  You would do it as MySQL's root user.

> 2)How do permissions work?

See the [Access Privilege System](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privilege-system.html) and [User Account Management](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-account-management.html) pages in the documentation.

> 3) Do I have to do anything on the MySQL side to make MySQL talk to Apache, or MySQL to talk to Python/Django?

Create a database, create a user for the database, and populate a database.  Additional details are going to be specific to the application.

> 4) Is there a good resource online that describes setting all of this up? I've found a bunch for using a database once it's in place, but none for the initial setup?

The [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/) is fantastic documentation.  You would run the `mysql` client if it is already installed in your system.  Recommendations specific to your distribution package cannot be provided without your distribution being identified.  If you want to use one of MySQL's releases directly, there will be a `README` and other incredibly verbose documentation within the tarball.

Answer (score 0):

If using MySQL from the commandline is giving you to much trouble you can also install [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net). Just download it to your web root (**NOT ON A PRODUCTION MACHINE!**) and then edit the sample.config.inc file to enter the mysql username/password and visit http://localhost/phpmyadmin